# How to remove and add features from OSMC and Openelec on RaspberryPi?

Tags: pi-2, openelec, osmc, media

I am exploring [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/) and [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/) for RaspberryPi. Menu options available in OSMC are:

- Videos
- Music
- Pictures
- My OSMC
- Favorites
- Programs etc..

Please help me how can I remove any of the menu options without affecting the rest of functionality. For e.g. I am interested in removing Music, and Pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know OSMC is based upon Kodi.

### The hard way

You can remove features using [skinning](http://kodi.wiki/view/XBMC_Skinning_Manual). If you're trying to remove a feature from an embedded skin such as Confluence the file system on which it resides might be read-only (this is true with OpenELEC, for instance). In that case, you'll have to re-package the skin in a ZIP file with your modifications and install the modified skin from a USB stick, for instance.

Kodi [skin addons](http://kodi.wiki/view/Skin_structure) have a file named `Home.xml`, which defines the controls, animations and styles of the home page. Run the following instruction to get a grasp of how windows are activated from the [home page](http://kodi.wiki/view/Window_IDs):

```
# grep -Rni ActivateWindow Home.xml
37:                <onclick>ActivateWindow(Videos)</onclick>
123:                <onclick>ActivateWindow(Music)</onclick>
164:                <onclick>ActivateWindow(Programs)</onclick>
255:                <onclick>ActivateWindow(1102)</onclick>
307:                <onclick>ActivateWindow(Settings)</onclick>
336:                <onclick>ActivateWindow(Favourites)</onclick>
```

In `Home.xml` find the line where window Music is shown. You'll probably find something like this:

```
    <control type="group" id="4250">
        <include>Window_OpenClose_Animation_Zoom</include>
        <posx>560r</posx>
        <posy>165</posy>
        <include>VisibleFadeEffect</include>
        <control type="button" id="4251">
            <onup>Control.SetFocus(4241)</onup>
            <ondown>Control.SetFocus(4261)</ondown>
            <onleft>Control.SetFocus(4201)</onleft>
            <description>Music Button</description>
            <posx>0</posx>
            <posy>0</posy>
            <width>540</width>
            <height>130</height>
            <font>-</font>
            <texturenofocus >home_4.png</texturenofocus>
            <texturefocus border="5">home_4_p.png</texturefocus>
            <onclick>ActivateWindow(Music)</onclick>
        </control>
        <control type="image">
            <description>Music Button Image</description>
            <posx>140r</posx>
            <posy>30</posy>
            <width>80</width>
            <height>80</height>
            <texture>music2.png</texture>
        </control>
        <control type="label">
            <description>Music label</description>
            <posx>170</posx>
            <posy>22</posy>
            <height>90</height>
            <width>250</width>
            <label>Music</label>
            <align>center</align>
            <aligny>center</aligny>
            <font>font40_title</font>
            <textcolor>FFFFFFFF</textcolor>
        </control>
    </control>
```

In the above excerpt the "Music" button is part of a group, which is to be removed. Add an XML tag `<visible>false</visible>` to the group, like this:

```
    <control type="group" id="4250">
        <include>Window_OpenClose_Animation_Zoom</include>
        <posx>560r</posx>
        <posy>165</posy>
        <include>VisibleFadeEffect</include>
        <visible>false</visible>
        <control type="button" id="4251">
        ...
```

Also note that in the above example `<include>VisibleFadeEffect</include>` is meant to apply visibility effects, which is useless here and can safely be removed.

Where to add the `<visible>false</visible>` tag depends on what skin you're modding. For example, in OpenELEC, you will find Confluence skin's `Home.xml` in directory `/storage/.kodi/addons/skin.<skin name>/720p/`. You can also search through OSMC for that file:

```
find / -name Home.xml
```

The file location includes the active skin name. Use `nano` or any available editor on OSMC to edit the file and apply your modifications.

**EDIT**: If you modify a skin that is currently in use you'll have to reload the skin for your changes to take effect:

```
kodi-send --action="ReloadSkin()"
```

The above command needs to be run on the Pi itself.

### The easy way

Some skins, such as [Amber](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Amber) have additional settings to configure which home buttons are visible.

Answer (score 1):

to make it short and easy:

if you use the default (kodi-)skin [Confluence](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Confluence), you can simply choose via [skin-settings](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Confluence/Settings#Home_window_options) which options should not appear.
[image: Conf Skin Home window 1]

this settings may also be present at some other skins...