# How do you refresh an OSMC skin?

Tags: osmc

I changed the menu entries in the OSMC skin settings, but my changes don't appear in the Home menu.

Rebooting and waiting for some time works, but is there a more reproduceable way to refresh my OSMC skin with the new configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify a skin that is currently in use you'll have to reload the skin for your changes to take effect:

kodi-send --action="ReloadSkin()"

Credits: [How to remove and add features from OSMC and Openelec on raspberry pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34909/how-to-remove-and-add-features-from-osmc-and-openelec-on-raspberry-pi)